# Uploading images in a node with WYSIWYG and TinyMCE 3.4.3

Tags: 7, wysiwyg

I am trying to put images in a node with the WYSIWYG editor and TinyMCE 3.4.3.
I uploaded an image, and with the editor I inserted the image in a node; the problem is that at first click the image doesn't appear in the node, and I must try another time to see the image.
Is it a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your `Input Filters` field-set while editing your node, in case of `filtered html` your image would not be presented. Try with `full html`.